# UITableView 'hidden' section causing more memory allocations every time on pull to refresh

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to see how to improve this code. I have a UITableView that I'm 'hiding' a section when the user taps on that section's header. I thought this was a pretty cool implementation I came up with, but it turns out when this section is hidden and the user pulls to refresh, about 1-2MB is added into memory every time they pull to refresh. If the section isn't hidden and they pull to refresh, no extra memory is allocated (the correct way/behavior).

I may be overlooking something, and would appreciate any help offered. Sorry for the lengthy code below:

Update: added cellForRowAtIndexPath method below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UILabel *userNameLabel = [self userNameLabel];
    UIView *requestsView = [self requestsView];
    UIButton *approveButton = [self approveButton];
    UIButton *denyButton = [self denyButton];
    UIImageView *profileImageView = [self profileImageView];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;

        [requestsView addSubview:approveButton];
        [requestsView addSubview:denyButton];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:requestsView];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:profileImageView];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:userNameLabel];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        userNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(82, 0, 167, 68);
        approveButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        denyButton.tag = indexPath.row;

        NSArray *keys = [self.tableDataSource objectForKey:@"Requests"];
        id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        userNameLabel.text = [aKey objectForKey:@"User"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[aKey objectForKey:@"URL"]]];
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
        request.timeoutInterval = 5.0;

        if ([imageCache objectForKey:aKey])
        {
            profileImageView.image = [imageCache objectForKey:aKey];
        }
        else
        {
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:
             ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (data)
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                    {
                        profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        [imageCache setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forKey:aKey];
                    });
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     profileImageView.image = [self profileImage];
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        requestsView.hidden = YES;
        NSArray *keys = [self.tableDataSource objectForKey:@"Friends"];
        id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        userNameLabel.text = [aKey objectForKey:@"User"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[aKey objectForKey:@"URL"]]];
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
        request.timeoutInterval = 5.0;

        if ([imageCache objectForKey:aKey])
        {
            profileImageView.image = [imageCache objectForKey:aKey];
        }
        else
        {
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:
             ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (data)
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                    {
                        profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        [imageCache setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forKey:aKey];
                    });
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     profileImageView.image = [self profileImage];
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        requestsView.hidden = YES;
        NSArray *keys = [self.tableDataSource objectForKey:@"Blocked"];
        id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        userNameLabel.text = [aKey objectForKey:@"User"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)displayBlockedUsers
{
    if (self.isShowingBlocked == YES)
    {
        self.isShowingBlocked = NO;
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    else
    {
        self.isShowingBlocked = YES;
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)friendRequests
{
    return [[self.tableDataSource objectForKey:@"Requests"]count];
}

- (NSInteger)friends
{
    return [[self.tableDataSource objectForKey:@"Friends"]count];
}

- (NSInteger)blockedUsers
{
    return [[self.tableDataSource objectForKey:@"Blocked"]count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2 && self.isShowingBlocked == NO)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
       return 68;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        if ([self friendRequests] < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 22;
        }
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        if ([self friends] < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 22;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self blockedUsers] < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 22;
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        if ([self friendRequests] < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return [self friendRequests];
        }
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        if ([self friends] < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return [self friends];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self blockedUsers] < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return [self blockedUsers];
        }
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:248.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 320, 22)];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.5];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    if (section == 0)
    {
        if ([self friendRequests] < 2)
        {
            headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Request",[self friendRequests]];
        }
        else
        {
            headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Requests",[self friendRequests]];
        }
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        if ([self friends] < 2)
        {
            headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Friend",[self friends]];
        }
        else
        {
            headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Friends",[self friends]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayBlockedUsers) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        theButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 22);

        [headerView addSubview:theButton];

        if (self.isShowingBlocked == YES)
        {
            headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Blocked - Tap to Hide",[self blockedUsers]];
        }
        else
        {
            headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Blocked - Tap to Show",[self blockedUsers]];
        }
    }

    return  headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory leak is more on topic for StackOverflow, but while this question is here and open, I'll make some comments on the stuff that's on topic...

Your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method really, really bothers me.

It can be replaced with this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch(section) {
        case 0:
            return [self friendRequests];
        case 1:
            return [self friends];
        default:
            return [self blockedUsers];
    }
}
```

These 3 methods will all return a value that is either 0 or evaluates false in `< 1`.  So the only time `< 1` evaluates true (and you want to return 0) is when the method itself is returning 0 (these methods can't return a negative number).

---

As for the memory issue, you'd need to include the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

---

Your code's readability could also be greatly enhanced by adding the following enum:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger FriendTableSections) {
    FriendRequests = 0,
    Friends        = 1,
    BlockedUsers   = 2
};
```

And then referring to the sections by their name in this enum, rather than by simply "0", "1", "2" (or "else").

Comment: Wow, thank you for the valid help with the switch statement. My previous method that I was doing definitely is not as light weight as the one you kindly provided. Also I will provide the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in a few

Comment: Just added the code in original question above